# axios get function not working in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am working on a web dev using ReactJs, NodeJs and Mysql. I got problem in displaying fetching data using axios.

here is my API :

```
app.get('/enduser',(req, res) => {
    let ENDUSER_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM enduser_tbl";
    let query = dbConn.query(ENDUSER_QUERY, (err, results) => {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err)
      } else {
        return res.status(200).json({"status": 200, "err" : null, "response": results});
      }
    });
  });
```

and I call the API in my reactjs page component

```
class ProjectList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            enduser_tbl : []
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const Url = "http://localhost:4000/enduser"
        await axios.get(Url)
        .then( enduser_tbl => {
            console.log(enduser_tbl.data)
            this.setState({
                enduser_tbl : enduser_tbl.data
            })
        })
    }

    render() {
        const enduser_tbl = this.state;
        return (
            <Container>
                { enduser_tbl.map ((enduser, project_id) => 
                    <ListGroup>
                        <ListGroup.Item key={project_id}> {enduser.project_type} </ListGroup.Item>
                    </ListGroup>
                )}
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

export default ProjectList
```

I got no error in my terminal but many problem appears in Chrome. here is the response from chrome 
[image]

Comment: Can you add the result of `console.log(enduser_tbl) just below `const enduser_tbl = this.state`

Comment: This kind of problems occurs when you are trying to use `map` which is not an Array.

Comment: @Jacob I add console.log .. and I got similar problem ..

Comment: @VikasSingh do you have problem solving for this kind of error?

Comment: @Shinichi1988 add screen shot of `console.log(enduser_tbl)` in the question

Answer (score 3):

Error in destructuring, missed curly brace ***const { enduser_tbl }***

```
render() {
        const { enduser_tbl = [] } = this.state;
        return (
            <Container>
                { enduser_tbl.map ((enduser, project_id) => 
                    <ListGroup>
                        <ListGroup.Item key={project_id}> {enduser.project_type} </ListGroup.Item>
                    </ListGroup>
                )}
            </Container>
        )
    }
```

For safe side:

```
const Url = "http://localhost:4000/enduser"
        await axios.get(Url)
        .then( { data: enduser_tbl = [] } => {
            console.log(data)
            this.setState({
                enduser_tbl
            })
        })
```

Comment: did u try default value to be empty object const { enduser_tbl = [] } = this.state;

Comment: i have updated and suggested few solutions. Please add error message

Comment: I still get the same problem enduser_tbl.map

Answer (score 0):

enduser_tbl.data will be undefined,
it will be either enduser_tbl.response or enduser_tbl which you are setting in your state.

```
    this.setState({
        enduser_tbl : enduser_tbl.response
    })
```

Comment: I though this one is the problem, but I got no response from server when i change enduser_tbl.data to enduser_tbl.response

Comment: const { enduser_tbl } = this.state;

Answer (score 0):

Two things, you are not getting the correct piece of the state in your render function. You also need to deal with that both the API call and `setState` are async, so you can't rely on it being defined when your component is rendered.

You can do it like this:

```
 const enduser_tbl = this.state.enduser_tbl || [];
 return (
    <Container>
        { enduser_tbl.map ((enduser, project_id) => 
            <ListGroup>
                <ListGroup.Item key={project_id}> {enduser.project_type} </ListGroup.Item>
                </ListGroup>
        )}
    </Container>
)
```

Comment: your response is kind of work, console.log is displaying the array, but the problem is still the same. enduser_tbl.map is not a function

Comment: This means that `this.state.enduser_tbl` is something, but not an array. Add a `console.log` just before the return statement in the render function to see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to map an object because this.state is an object. Try changing the code as given below.

```
class ProjectList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            enduser_tbl : []
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const Url = "http://localhost:4000/enduser"
        await axios.get(Url)
        .then( enduser_tbl => {
            console.log(enduser_tbl.data)
            this.setState({
                enduser_tbl : enduser_tbl.data
            })
        })
    }

    render() {
        const enduser_tbl = this.state.enduser_tbl;
        return (
            <Container>
                { enduser_tbl.map ((enduser, project_id) => 
                    <ListGroup>
                        <ListGroup.Item key={project_id}> {enduser.project_type} </ListGroup.Item>
                    </ListGroup>
                )}
            </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error rises because you are not passing array to map function please add below code and let me know is it work for you are not

```
componentDidMount = async (e) =>{
const url = "http://localhost:4000/enduser"
try{
const res = await axios.get(url)
this.setState({
 enduser_tbl :res.data
})
}
ctach(ex){
console.log(ex)
}
}
```

Comment: put it the code in try catch block and check the console i think  it goes in exception

Answer (score 0):

First, check your API response it might look like this

```js
 {
  "status": 200, 
  "response": [{...}, {...}]
 }
```

then when receiving your data make sure you've set it to the state properly
e.g:

```js
await axios.get(Url)
  .then(enduser_tbl => {
    this.setState({
      enduser_tbl: enduser_tbl.response
    })
  })
```

finally, make sure that you've destructured it properly just like xdeepkav said e.g

`const { enduser_tbl } = this.state;`

The error the you're encountering is because enduser_tbl can't be read as mappable data/array. To make it clear here's an example of your error

[image]

Comment: Have you already check your API response? can you show it here?

Comment: I solve the problem using this :
  componentDidMount() {
        fetch("http://localhost:4000/enduser")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(enduser_tbl => this.setState ({
                enduser_tbl: enduser_tbl.data
            }))

            //error message
            .catch(error => {
                this.setState({ error: error.message } )
              });
      }